# R) Convert Seurat object to URD

Tags: r, seurat

I am a beginner in R trying to analyze my scRNA-seq data with URD to draw a tree.
For this, I want to convert my seurat object to URD.
So I followed a scripted written by Jeff Farrell below.

```
base.path <- "~/urd-cluster-bushra/"

# Load Seurat object that has been cropped to hypothalamus cells

object.seurat <- readRDS(paste0(base.path, "obj/retina.new_seurat.rds"))

# Convert to URD object\
suburd <- seuratToURD(object.seurat)
```

But, when I run seuratToURD function, I get the following error:

```
Error in as.matrix(seurat.object@data) : no slot of name "data" for this object of class "Seurat"
```

Is there anyone to solve the problem? I desperately need your helps!

Thanks!

Comment: That error is saying that in your seurat object, the slot it is looking for (data) doesn't exist. Without more info it wouldn't be possible to give a more specific answer.

Comment: you might be reading an object that is made by Seurat2 and you are running seurat 3